# How to get a list of current Oracle CDBs on server

Tags: oracle, containers

If I have a server with one or more [CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/glossary.htm#GUID-135FF536-DE9B-40CF-9F42-C246762BD77F)s, what command can I run on the server in order to obtain a list where each item uniquely identifies one of the CDBs?

(a "CDB" is an Oracle Container Database)

**Note 1:** 
I realize that it is rare to have more than one CDB on a server.  But in that case I would still want to obtain the unique CDB name of that one CDB.

**Note 2:** I know that the command `cat /etc/oratab` will list a bunch of DB installations on the server.  But this includes installations that no longer exist.  I want a list of only the currently existing CDB installations.

Comment: [How to see list of databases in Oracle?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27725/2047)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I list running database instances. Container-databases or non-container databases:

```
  cat >> ~/.bash_profile <<EOF
  oinst() {
      /bin/ps -ef | grep ora_lgw[r] | awk '{print $8}' | sed -e 's/ora_lg[w]r_//'
  }
  EOF

  $oinst
  CDB1
  CDB2
  CDB3
```

If database instances are not running you are left with information from  `/etc/oratab`, `init<SID>.ora`, `orapw<SID>` or database-files on ASM, filesystem or RMAN.